# Regex to format nested BB [quote] tag

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am trying to turn:

```
[quote]Hello![/quote]
```

Into:

```
<div class="quoted-text">Hello!</div>
```

This code is the closest I have it to working:

```
var r = new Regex(@"\[quote\]([^\]]+)\[\/quote\]", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
rawComment = r.Replace(rawComment, "<div class=\"quoted-text\">$1</div>");
```

However, for nested quotes it doesn't come around correctly.  It only seems to convert the inner most quote.  A test case is:

```
[quote]
    test
    [quote]
        nest
        [quote]
            nest
        [/quote]
    [/quote]
[/quote]
```

Which comes out as:

```
[quote]
    test
    [quote]
        nest
        <div class="quoted-text">
            nest
        </div>
    [/quote]
[/quote]
```

Can anyone show me how to make this work as expected?

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it writing a parser. It was far too difficult to manage all the conversion using Regular Expressions. Hope you find an easier solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why you would need to parse the quote as a block.  Therefore, the simplest solution would be to just replace each token with the one you want.  Here's a example for LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{

    var rawComment =
"[quote]\n" +
"   test\n" +
"   [quote]\n" +
"       nest\n" +
"       [quote]\n" +
"           nest\n" +
"       [/quote]\n" +
"   [/quote]\n" +
"[/quote]\n";

    var start = new Regex(@"\[quote\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var end = new Regex(@"\[\/quote\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    rawComment = start.Replace(rawComment, "<div class=\"quoted-text\">");
    rawComment = end.Replace(rawComment, "</div>");

    rawComment.Dump();
}
```

This produces the following:

```
<div class="quoted-text">
  test
  <div class="quoted-text">
    nest
    <div class="quoted-text">
      nest
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but malformed comments (for example more [quotes] than [/quotes]) would break the entire page

Comment: @TomGullen: There is no other way round for that case of malformed structure. Why not you use a `stack` for that?

Comment: I would consider validation of the markup to be a separate concern from markup transformation.